# Where can I find automobile insurance claims data set?

Tags: machine-learning

I really need a dataset about automobile insurance claims to train and test learning algorithms.

I found references to Masachussets PIP claims data and to Spanish claims data in many scientific articles, but I couldn't find them...

The best would be to find claims which concern just insurance third party liability extensions: I mean theft, fire, acts of vandalism, atmospheric agents. But also claims concerning third party liability insurance would be great.

Comment: Did you find any dataset from this inquery? could you please share it?
@Joe San Pietro is there any data description avaiable for this dataset (Auto Insurance Claims - Automobile Insurance claims including location, policy type and claim amount). I am struggling with the diff between 'claim amount' and 'Total Claim Amount' for instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

A couple of new automobile insurance claim data sets have become available since this question was asked. Thought I'd list them here:

### Emcien:

Published: Auto Insurance Claims - Automobile Insurance claims including
   location, policy type and claim amount
   http://dyzz9obi78pm5.cloudfront.net/app/image/id/560ec66d32131c9409f2ba54/n/Auto_Insurance_Claims_Sample.csv

### Allstate:

Held a "claims severity" competition on Kaggle. 
   https://www.kaggle.com/c/allstate-claims-severity

Answer (score 4):

The book “Data: A Collection of Problems from Many Fields for the Student and Research Worker” by Andrews and Herzberg has such a data set as:

Table 68.1 Third Party Motor Insurance for Sweden, 1977 (112642
        bytes)

When there is an answer to this question:  [The data from "Data: A Collection of Problems from Many Fields for the Student and Research Worker" by Andrews and Herzberg](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/the-data-from-data-a-collection-of-problems-from-many-fields-for-the-student-a)
you can find the data from there.

And here is a direct link for the data:
http://www.statsci.org/data/general/motorins.txt

Answer (score 2):

You can find several datasets for R [here](http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/R/web/CASdatasets-manual.pdf), for the book [Computational Actuarial Science with R](https://www.crcpress.com/Computational-Actuarial-Science-with-R/Charpentier/p/book/9781138033788).

**Package ‘CASdatasets’**

> A completed project by the Insurance Risk and Finance Research Centre (www.IRFRC.com) hasassembled a unique dataset from Large Commercial Risk losses in Asia-Pacific (APAC) coveringthe period 2000-2013.  The data was generously contributed by one global reinsurance companyand two large Lloyd’s syndicates in London.  This dataset is the result of the project co-lead by DrMilidonis (IRFRC and University of Cyprus) and Enrico Biffis (Imperial College Business School),which can be referred to as the IRFRC LCR Dataset.