# The data from "Data: A Collection of Problems from Many Fields for the Student and Research Worker" by Andrews and Herzberg

Tags: data-request

"Data: A Collection of Problems from Many Fields for the Student and Research Worker" by Andrews and Herzberg : [https://www.amazon.com/Data-Collection-Problems-Research-Statistics/dp/0387961259/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1465372463&sr=1-1&keywords=DATA+andrews+Herzberg](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961259)
is a book with data and descriptions for teaching and learning statistics and data analysis.  The datasets from the book used to be on the internet, but now I cannot find them!

Specifically, they used to be on statlib, but now that seems inaccessible too!
Anybody knows where that data collection can be found now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [StatLib](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/Andrews/) web site seems to be available again, but oddly, not all datasets from Andrews and Herzberg can be retrieved (20 out of 100 are missing).

There is also a copy at [Duke](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring01/sta114/data/andrews.html), with all datasets.

Answer (score 2):

I found it finally, the main statlib site seems to be down but there is a mirror at  ftp://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/pub/math/statlib/oldindex.html
and the Andrews and Herzberg data can be fount at
ftp://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/pub/math/statlib/datasets/Andrews/